# Improving Asset Publisher

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to add another form into the configuration.jsp page of Asset Publisher.
Read a parameter called Segmentation.
And show all the content with the same Segmentation tag assigned.

Looking to the public code of Asset Publisher, I'm not able to understand:
1. Where is Asset Publisher reading the Web Content?
2. How I can read this content adding this new filter?
(I want to implement a Hook)

Hope that someone can help me,
Thank you for the help,
Oriol

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show content based on tag assigned to it, then there is configuration in Asset Publisher for that. Refer below screenshot:
[image]